Geometric interpretation of an equivalence relation
Consider $X=[-1,1]\subset \mathbb{R} $ with the standard subspace topology. Define the equivalence relation $a \sim b \iff [(a=b) $ or $(a=-b$ and $|a|<1)]$. My Professor suggested this as an example of a Hausdorff space $X$ and an equivalence relation $\sim$ such that $X/\sim$ is not Hausdorff. The points $-1$ and $1$ are "attached" to $(-1,1)$ in the intuitive sense of the continuity of the line and they are the only such numbers. What I struggle to understand is how (or perhaps I should say where) to visualize $[-1]$ and $[1]$, since they are not equal and cannot be both "attached" to the projection of $(-1,1)$, which is $[0,1)$. My Professor said that they can be thought of being "indefinitely close to each other and to $[0,1)$ but still separate", where "indefinitely close to $[0,1)$" follows from the fact that as soon as you move from $\pm1$ to the interior of $(-1,1)$ you get points which are glued together. However, I fail to understand what this really means, since no matter how close $[-1]$ and $[1]$ are to $[0,1)$, the continuity is still lost! Here is a sketch of what the equivalence relation looks like. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!


Your sketch is about as good as it gets in terms of visualization (and it's pretty much what I would have drawn, so you've got that down). I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for beyond this in terms of intuition, but one exercise you might do to understand this space better is to show that a sequence in $X / {{\sim}}$ converges to $1$ if and only if it converges to $-1$ (this should give some intuition for what it means that these two points are "indefinitely close to each other").

@BenSteffan what "bothers" me is the loss of continuity as I said in the end of my post

I'm not sure what "continuity" is supposed to mean. If you're talking about the drawing, then yes, the two points seem detached from the real line, but this is an artifact of visualization. You cannot draw this space in a truly faithful manner. That's why you should do the exercise I proposed, to get a feel for this space that doesn't rely on the visual. But on the level of theory "continuity" really doesn't have any meaning; there's only sets, and topologies on them, and together they make up what we call spaces, of which your example is one.

@BenSteffan I see. So there's no way to draw this quotient space. This was clear, thank you

Adding to the comments of @Ben Steffan, the reason you can't draw it correctly is because your space is not Hausdorff, while drawing means you're embedding your space in $\Bbb{R^2}$, which is Hausdorff so any subspace of it will also be Hausdorff.
